# duplicate key error in copy activity azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a problem, when trying to copy data from 1 Postgresql database to another Postgresql database with the copy command in Azure data factory I get a duplicate key error (as seen in the picture below). I have the [Fault tolerance enabled in the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVxZG.png). Has anyone had the same problem in the past and knows a solution?
[see here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPTTm.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce similar issue in my environment

[image]

> Failure happened on 'Sink' side. 'Type=Npgsql.PostgresException,Message=23505: duplicate key value violates unique co

**The error is causing because your source and sink has same primary key** because when I tried to copy data from one table to another table with same Primary key it throwed me this error.

To resolve this, make sure your both source and sink does not have similar primary keys.

When I tried to copy data from one table to another table which doesn't have similar primary key. It copied data successfully.

- **Sample data**
  [image]
- **Pipeline runned successfully.**
  [image]
- **Output**
  [image]